# django admin truncate words in list display

Tags: django, django-admin

I am returning a text field in admin list display and it is too long so i want to truncate it..

```
def comment(self, obj):
    return '{{{}|truncatewords:10}}'.format(obj.comment)
comment.allow_tags = True
comment.short_description = "Comment"
```

It is not giving me the comment. I have included the comment in list_display
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot duplicate the attribute's name, use a custom definition instead, e.g.

```
def get_comment(self, obj):
    return ...
get_comment.allow_tags = True
get_comment.short_description = "Comment"
```

Also you should use truncatewords as a function when not using in inside a template

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import truncatewords

def get_comment(self, obj):
    return truncatewords(obj.comment, 10)
get_comment.allow_tags = True
get_comment.short_description = "Comment"
```

Comment: truncateword is not defined

Comment: you probably need to import the function